# mysql slow binlog, why not directIO

Tags: mysql

In mysql, if log_bin is enabled and sync_binlog=1, the "insert+commit" operation will be very slow. That's because mysql will invoke fdatasync in each commit.
However the data is stored in SSD. I think directIO without fdatasync will be much faster.

So, my question is that why binlog doesn't support directIO and if it does, how to enable it?

Comment: I dont think mysql always write to binlogs. If that was the case `Flush logs` doesnot make sense

Comment: @georgecj11 that's what setting `sync_binlog` > 0 enables.

Comment: Raised a request in mysql site.
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81680